# Azure API to get Portal Settings

Tags: rest, azure, portal, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I'm wondering whether there's a REST API (or an alternative method) on Azure that would give the portal settings for a particular subscription.
Things like Language, Regional Format, the selected Theme and etc.
I can't find anything on the subject on the MSDN's Azure Reference document.

Comment: Pretty sure those things are user specific.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no way of programmatically reaching those information, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't available today. Can you put in a feature request? Please include a little more information about why you want it to help prioritize.

http://aka.ms/azureportalfeedback

As a side note, AAD user accounts have a preferredLanguage setting that might be useful. The portal doesn't use this today, but might in the future.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#UserEntity

Comment: The reviewers were wrong in this case. This answer is just fine.